# Duplicate `operationId` with Multiclass API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I try to deploy my Cloud Endpoints Framework api using `gcloud service-management deploy openapi.json`, I get many errors similar to:

```
ERROR: openapi.json: Operation 'get' in path '/sd/v1/groups/{id}': operationId 'SdGet' has duplicate entry
```

Inspecting the generated `openapi.json` document, I see it has many duplicated `operationId`s. For example notice both of these use `SdGet`:

```
{
  ...
  "paths": {
      "/sd/v1/feeds/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "SdGet",
        ...
      }
    },
    "/sd/v1/groups/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "SdGet",
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My backend is in Java. I have a multiclass API using inheritance, which seems to confrm to the recommendations in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/multiclass#using_java_inheritance). Here are the relevant parts for this example:

```
@Api(name = "sd", ...)
public class Endpoints { ... }

public class FeedEndpoints extends Endpoints {
    @ApiMethod(
        path = "feeds/{id}",
        name = "feeds.get",
        httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public Feed get(...) { ... }

    ...
}

public class GroupEndpoints extends Endpoints {
    @ApiMethod(
        path = "groups/{id}",
        name = "groups.get",
        httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public Group get(...) { ... }

    ...
}
```

To generate `openapi.json` I modeled my config after Google's [getting started](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) guide. So in `pom.xml` I have something like this, which lets me generate it with the command `mvn exec:java -DGetSwaggerDoc`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>GetSwaggerDoc</id>
        ...
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    ...
                    <configuration>
                        ...
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>get-swagger-doc</argument>
                            <argument>--hostname=echo-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog</argument>
                            <argument>--war=target/blah-1.0-SNAPSHOT</argument>
                            <argument>blah.FeedEndpoints</argument>
                            <argument>blah.GroupEndpoints</argument>
                            ...
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    ...
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I define things differently so that the generated api specification does not use duplicate ids?

Comment: What is in the `Endpoints` base class besides the annotation?

Comment: @saiyr a handful static and 2 protected helper methods. None of them are annotated.

Comment: This is a bug in the framework. If you'd like to file a bug, you can visit [Github](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java). It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@saiyr informs me this is a bug in the framework (see comments on the question), so I filed a report [here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/issues/97). For now I worked around it by renaming the API methods in all my endpoint classes to be unique, like this:

```
@Api(...)
public class Endpoints { ... }

public class FeedEndpoints extends Endpoints {
    @ApiMethod(...)
    public Feed getFeed(...) { ... }
    ...
}

public class GroupEndpoints extends Endpoints {
    @ApiMethod(...)
    public Group getGroup(...) { ... }
    ...
}
```